# Using Identity.UI in WebAPI project

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.0

I'm pretty new to Asp.NET and would like some more information on how to proceed. I have a standard WebAPI project which contains the standard weather template - I'm trying to apply some authentication via registering/logging in. I know theres a way to have template do it for you when create project, but for web api it doesn't let you do a local database which I want.

So right now I've attached the Identity.UI package to give me access to this method and generate the migration for identity tables

```
 services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
   .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

which allows me to use the UserManager to register a user and for login I do this:

```
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) return BadRequest();

    var result = await m_userManager.FindByNameAsync(user.Email);
    var correct = await m_userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(result, user.Password);

    if (!correct) return BadRequest();

    return Ok(new { token = m_tokenService.BuildToken(user.Email) });
```

My question is a correct way of handling registering and login via WebAPI because the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI package as the name suggests provides razor pages for login/registering which I don't really need which makes me believe this isn't correct. Is there downside/problem doing it this way, or is this a cleaner way of doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI package provides a razor page for login/registration that seems redundant for web api .

For implementing Microsoft identity on web api to handle basic individual user accounts , you could try to use JWT tokens , refer to the following links which are good tutorials about using JwtBearer Authentication in an ASP.NET Core API Project :

https://wildermuth.com/2018/04/10/Using-JwtBearer-Authentication-in-an-API-only-ASP-NET-Core-Project

https://dotnetdetail.net/asp-net-core-3-0-web-api-token-based-authentication-example-using-jwt-in-vs2019/

Comment: The idea I'm going for is to have a authentication database (one supplied by UI package) to hold account info and roles. Then if a user is registered I will supply a jwt token back to the client and they can access the rest of apis. I'm trying to avoid having to do my own autnetication database/usermanager stuff since it already exists . The second link you posted is kinda what im trying to achieve right now it uses but it uses AddIdentity rather than default - does this achieve the same thing?

Comment: @A.A , [AddDefaultIdentity](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/release/2.2/src/Identity/UI/src/IdentityServiceCollectionUIExtensions.cs#L47-L63) was introduced in ASP.NET Core 2.1. Calling **AddDefaultIdentity** is similar to calling **AddIdentity** , **AddDefaultUI** and **AddDefaultTokenProviders** .

Refer to https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/issues/8434